# When is data retrieved from MYSQL DB for Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am transmitting a lot of data from a MYSQL database within a codeigniter application.

Would like to know at what point in the process will the database be extracted from the database.

```
1) $query = $this->db->query("Select * from table");
2) $query->num_rows()
3) $query->result();
```

I know that according to the documentation "The query() function returns a database result object" however does this object contain the actual records or is it fetched from the database when we call result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking about when the actual data transfer happens between MySQL and PHP.

Data is transferred from the server *immediately* after the `query` command and then stored internally, so you can later fetch the rows. If you think about it, it makes perfect sense, as you don't want the fetch of each row to block and your app wait for the network traffic.

You can verify this (I just did it) with putting a sleep between the query and the fetch, and running tcpdump/wireshark to capture the network traffic.

Note: The codeigniter DB class is just the wrapper around the builtin mysql driver, so this is not codeigniter specific.

Answer (score 0):

As per the actual implementations of any database connection, the query statement actually fetches only the resource link.

The resource descriptor will give the details such as number of rows returned/affected.

However, there is an internal pointer that is maintained by the driver which points to one of the record within the linked resource.

When the record is accessed via the result(), the current record is fetched and the pointers are internally modified.

So, it is the `$query->result()` when the data is actually fetched.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $query = $this->db->query("Select * from table");
```

This will give you the reources id and if you want all data from db then you write :-

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

$result = $this->db->($query)->result_array();
```

And when you want to view your result you can do like this -

```
print_r($result);
```

so conclusion is it is the `result_array()` that really fetched the data from db

Comment: that's what your see from the viewpoint of your app, but that's not what happening behind the scenes